# iphone crashes on the first time installed

Tags: iphone, crash, exc-bad-access

my app crashes with EXC BAD ACCESS
i've added NSZombieEnabled = YES to the arguments of my executable.
it gives me that log: 
[CFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3c26340 
and crashes that happens only on the first time the app is installed on the simulator.. i press Build and Go again the app works as it should.

given that the address 0x3c26340 is not the NSArray address that the app crashes on.
(after setting breakpoints i discovered it crashes on NSArray access but not with the address shown in the log!!!!!!!!! )

also that address is the same address when i remove the app from the simulator and crashes again on the first installation. ( The Address remains the same!!!! )

can anybody please help?

thanks in advance

Comment: Not without code. You're probably creating some object from stored data. When the data doesn't exists, you create the array but you don't retain it, which would have been done when the data was stored. I've had this in the past and have been searching for the problem for quite a time, but eventually solved it by checking all my stored data 'fetches'.

Comment: i've checked all the memory addresses on the debug window before the app crashes and no instance has that address .. the most strange thing is that the address remains the same

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need is a stack trace, or at the very least the last function called before the crash, to figure out exactly what array variable is being messed with at the crash.

The other thing that could possibly be happening is an array being accessed without being properly initialized. This would cause the variable to have a consistent number that isn't the address of any object. I would still go with JoostK's comment that this has something to do with a stored object that is created after the first run of the app.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
i revised all the code paths setting breakpoints and checking all variable values and so,
you sure know that there's no stacktrace provided for this kind of exceptions, and sure i thought of making a break point every step :)
but the thing is that it crashes right between the calling of 2 functions just in the middle of nowhere which is driving me crazy!